# How to add a property validation before a specific maven goal?

Tags: maven

For my project I'm using the maven jib plugin to create and push a docker image, it is defined in the master pom dependency management like this:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${jib-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <from>
                        <image>${baseImage}</image>                     
                    </from>
                    <to>
                        <image>${docker-registry.url}/${project.artifactId}</image>
                        <tags>
                            <tag>${project.version}</tag>
                        </tags>
                    </to>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Notice that the base image is taken from a property that the developer just inserts in their project.
Once the configuration is in place the "compile" phase will trigger the plugin:

```
mvn compile jib:build
```

Now, I'd like to put a plugin before this one (ideally before the phase "compile" with the argument "jib:build") that checks if the ${baseImage} property value comes from a list of allowed images and in case it is not true halts the build. Is this possible? 
Ditto for the docker-registry.url: I'd like to restrict the docker registries to a set of allowed values.

Comment: you could take a look at https://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireProperty.html

Comment: Ok so I would have to put a regex there...could solve my problem but if there was something more immediate would be better...moreover what if it is null or empty?